# Loop through tree structure of directories in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have tons of XML files in the Azure Blob Storage. The files are saved in a tree structure. Having a root directory called QA, then in QA we have sub-directories for years [Eg :2015, 2016].
And inside each year folder there are sub directories for each month [Eg: 01,02, 03 ... 12]. Inside each month there are sub directories for each day.I have these xml files in these day folders.

I wrote a code to process the xml files and save them in the same location,but the code I wrote works only if I show the exact directory where the files are present, it doesn't loop through into inner directories. How to make it loop through each of these sub - directories and files.

```
QA\2015\01\01\file1<datetimestamp>.xml
    -------01\file2<datetimestamp>.xml
    -------01\file3<datetimestamp>.xml
  ------\01\02\file1<datetimestamp>.xml
  ------\01\02\file2<datetimestamp>.xml
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ------\02\01\file1<datetimestamp>.xml
  ...
  ...
  ...
QA\2016\01\01\file1<datetimestamp>.xml
    -------01\file2<datetimestamp>.xml
    -------01\file3<datetimestamp>.xml
  ------\01\02\file1<datetimestamp>.xml
  ------\01\02\file2<datetimestamp>.xml
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ------\02\01\file1<datetimestamp>.xml
```

I am looking for some way to implement a code like

```
for (year )
    {
        for (month)
            {
                for day
                    <My code goes here - pick the files scrub unnecessary data and save as a new file in same location>
                     --- Now I need to fiigure out how to save in same location as well
            }
    }
```

Also, This doesn't work for me : `var blobs = container.ListBlobs(prefix: "container-directory", useFlatBlobListing: true);` as I am not listing. I want to goto each directory and process the files

My Code :  get nothing but errors

```
     CloudBlobClient bc = sa.CreateCloudBlobClient();

    // Get a reference to the container
    CloudBlobContainer container = bc.GetContainerReference(ContainerNameStr);

    var blobs = bc.ListBlobs(prefix: InitialLocDir, useFlatBlobListing: true, blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.Metadata);
    foreach (CloudBlockBlob blob in blobs)
    {
        blob.AcquireLease(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), null);
        var blocks = blob.DownloadBlockList(BlockListingFilter.Committed).ToList();
        foreach (var block in blocks)
        {
            MemoryStream sourceStream = new MemoryStream();
            blob.DownloadRangeToStream(sourceStream, 0, block.Length);
            // Modify the stream here
            Gpg gpg1 = new Gpg();
            MemoryStream destStream = new MemoryStream();
            gpg1.Passphrase = Phrase;
            gpg1.BinaryPath = @"C:/Program Files (x86)/GNU/GnuPG/gpg2.exe";
            sourceStream.Position = 0;
            gpg1.Decrypt(sourceStream, destStream);

            destStream.Position = 0;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(destStream);
            string xmlfile = "";
            xmlfile = reader.ReadToEnd();
            blob.PutBlock(block.Name, destStream, null, null, null, null);
            Console.WriteLine(xmlfile);
        }

        Console.Read();

        blob.PutBlockList(blocks, null, null, null);
    }
```

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly, you want to first list subdirectories for year, then for each year you want to list subdirectories for months and the do the same for days in a month. Only after that you want to list the files and process those files. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Well, the files are present only in the inner most directory that is day folders. The code I wrote only works for specific  directory. And yes your understanding is right. Updated the question with my code.

Comment: @GauravMantri : I want the program to give path like getdirectory(QA/2015/01) inside the for loop of day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same directory structure with an additional folder for each hour in the day. I process each blob in each folder and 'clean' them.

Some pseudo code

- blobs = cloudBlobClient.ListBlobs(prefix:rootFolder,useFlatBlobListing:true,blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.Metadata);
- foreach(blob in blobs)

  - blob.[AcquireLease](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.icloudblob.acquirelease.aspx)
  - var blocks = blob.[DownloadBlockList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadblocklist.aspx)(BlockListingFilter.Committed).ToList();
  - foreach(block in blocks)

    - blob.DownloadRangeToStream(dataStream,position,block.Length)
    - modify the stream if necessary
    - If modified, blob.PutBlock(block.Name,adjustedStream...)
- blob.PutBlockList(blocksToPush, new AccessCondition() { LeaseId = leaseId })

  client.ListBlobs basically does the job enumerating all the blobs across all the folders. Then it is just a matter of iterating each blob file and gettings its blocks and processing them.

Comment: Wow! I am looking for something similar like this. Can you please elaborate your pseudo code ? Also couldn't find AcqureLease Method or DownloadBlockList. It would be a great help if you can put the code to do that.

Comment: blob.PutBlockList(blocks, null, null, null);  results n error . What should be the first argument for PutBlockList ?

Comment: I modified my code with yours [updated the question]. But it doesnt work , I get errors. Can you please check if i am doing the right way ?

Comment: @HadoopAddict I have updated how I make the call to PutBlockList. The 'blocksToPush' is the list of blocks that you have modified. 
What errors do you get?